# differences between multithread and multitask

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

What's different between **multithread** programming and **multitask** in C#.net4?
I need some technical reviews.
I am doing some research on the topic and I need something to help me.

Comment: Please link to both terms so we know _exactly_ what you mean.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/parallelextensions/thread/389a2bd2-39e5-4078-80ac-e606162c99be/

Comment: First google hit... http://zone.ni.com/devzone/cda/tut/p/id/6424

Answer (score 2):

Multitasking is a somewhat imprecise term that can mean different things in different contexts.  It can refer to:

- multi-processing (time sharing between separate processes),
- multiple threads or tasks in an embedded system,
- a particular form or framework for of multi-threading,
- even just plain multithreading

I think that the 'multitasking' term you're asking about is regarding the "Task Parallelism" support added in .NET 4: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx

That model would fall into the 3rd item above - it's an abstraction for performing work in parallel that uses threading but tries to keep much of the mechanics of threads under the covers.